# INSERT new rows into table from a list of values if they don't already exist there

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table(tblEntities) that contains the following columns:
ID(identity)
MEANING(varchar)
START_DATE(DateTime)
STOP_DATE(DateTime, Allows Nulls)

I have a long list of values I want to add to this table.  This list is obtained by querying another table(tblOther):

```
SELECT ITEMNAME
FROM tblOther
GROUP BY ITEMNAME
```

So for each item generated by the query above, I want to:

- Insert a new row with using ITEMNAME from the query above as MEANING in the tblEntities table IF it does not already exist in the table
- Set the START_DATE as '1/1/1900'
- Set the STOP_DATE as the current date

How can I accomplish this?  Is it a matter of using a WHERE IN from the list or do I need to create some function to loop through.

Thanks for the help,

Comment: It's a matter of using `WHERE NOT EXISTS()`

Comment: MERGE can do it better 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

YOu could use this query,

```
INSERT INTO tblEntities (Meaning, Start_Date, Stop_Date)
SELECT DISTINCT(ItemName), '1900-01-01', getdate()
FROM tblOther
WHERE tblOther NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT(Meaning) FROM tblEntities)
```

Or for even more optimized query, you could use LEFT JOIN

```
INSERT INTO tblEntities (Meaning, Start_Date, Stop_Date)
SELECT DISTINCT(ItemName), '1900-01-01', getdate()
FROM tblOther O
LEFT JOIN tblEntities E ON E.Meaning = O.ItemName
WHERE O.ItemName  IS NULL
```